# CentOS 6, Webmin, Virtualmin

Tags: linux, dns, centos, hostname, nslookup

I have a VPS account running CentOS 6 with 3 IP addresses allocated to it for various SSL certificates.

When I do an NSLookup for the IP addresses they resolve and display the wrong name.

94.76.252.102 resolves geldverdienensofort.com when it should resolve valentms.com
94.76.252.104 resolves geldverdienensofort.com when it should resolve linux-distro.co.uk
94.76.252.130 resolves . when it should resolve booksndvds.com

I have set up reverse DNS for all 3 IP's in Bind and the hostname of the server is set to valentms.com.

How do I go about changing the name resolved by NSLookup to match the domain name they point to.

Regards
Jim